# socket.bind does not raise error when in a loop, but does otherwise

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I get different socket.bind() behaviour if the bind call is in a loop, and don't understand why this would be.  Example:

```
>>> af, socktype, proto = 10, 1, 6
>>> for i in xrange(2):
...     sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
...     sock.bind(('5.9.109.188', 0))
... 
>>> 
>>> sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
>>> sock.bind(('5.9.109.188', 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The exception that is raised when this is not in the loop is the behaviour I expect, because the socket family is 10 (AF_INET6) but the source address that I'm trying to bind to is 2 (AF_INET).

I don't see any reason why this would occur in the [bind source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/socketmodule.c).

For what it's worth, the background is that I'm using socket.create_connection ([source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/socket.py)) and it loops through the results of getaddrinfo calling bind inside the loop, and should (if I understand correctly) fail when the source address is inappropriate, moving on to the next set of results.  Instead, because this does not fail in a loop, I end up with a socket that is IPv6 even though I have specified an IPv4 source address.

This is Python 2.7.10 on Debian (testing/Stretch):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10+ (default, Oct 10 2015, 09:11:24) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151003] on linux2
```

Installed via aptitude:

```
ii  python2.7                        2.7.10-5                      amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
```

Comment: Is your question, "Why is an IPv6 socket allowed to bind to an IPv4 address?" The answer is that the platform supports mapping of IPv4 addresses into IPv6, like `::FFFF:192.168.1.1`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that answers why the exception isn't raised in the loop.  So why is it raised outside of the loop?  If it's that there is already a socket bound to that address (even though I'm leaving the port choice to the OS), then why does the exception not get raised the second time around the loop?

Comment: At the time the exception was raised, the bind failed. To understand why in more detail, look closely at the exact circumstances of the case where it failed. Was the address you attempted to bind to assigned to that machine?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes (but even if not, then why would it succeed in the loop in that case?).  I pasted all of the code in at once, so it happened as quickly as the content could get from the buffer to the repl and get executed.  So the circumstances between the second loop bind() and the one outside of the loop are identical other than anything that happened in the fraction of a second between.

Comment: So the bind in the loop took the address and the bind outside the loop failed because the address was in use.